# UTF-8 Characters in XMLHttpRequest are corrupted

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, utf-8, xmlhttprequest

I'm using an `XMLHttpRequest` for inserting some rows to a MYSQL database. I defined the relevant table columns to accept UTF-8 characters (`Collation: utf8_general_ci`).

The query being initiated from the request is:

```
INSERT INTO e4s_event_list (producerID, eventID, eventName, eventDescription, eventVenue, eventDate) 
VALUES('2', 'f49c104b-6193-47b7-b196-ca914e5238c4', 'בכורה מאת שרון אייל וטאבולה ראסה מאת אוהד נהרין', '', 'Conversion Venue - 0', '2012-06-04T20:30:00')
```

If I query this from the `phpMyAdmin` the `eventDescription` column gets the desired value with no problem . But when the query being initiated from the `XMLHttpRequest`, the `eventDescription` column gets this value:

`×‘×›×•×¨×” ×ž××ª ×©×¨×•×Ÿ ××™×™×œ ×•×˜××‘×•×œ×”..`

My current headers are:

```
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

I've tried to change `Content-Type` to:

```
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

But then, for some reason, the request doesn't work at all.

I know it isn't a database definition issue, because All other queries that aren't initiated from an `XMLHttpRequest` are **not** being messed up.

How can I insert the Hebrew characters correctly ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that MySQL believes PHP is passing the string on as another character encoding (ISO-8859-1 for example). If that's the case you can fix this by sending this query to MySQL before writing the data to the database:

```
SET NAMES=UTF8;
```

Comment: Ahhh, I indeed forgot to do `mysql_query("set names utf8")` inside the `request` code. Thanks !

Comment: Good that it was that simple :)